# How to change the textColor of all items on the popup of an Android spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, textcolor

I'm working on an app that presents a user with two graphic objects.  Each object is associated with a corresponding spinner from which the user can select one of a handful of attributes.   Touching one spinner deactivates the other (This is handled outside of spinner.setEnabled.)

The view contains a single seekbar from which the user can control the range of values applied to the most recently selected attribute.

Color is one of the attributes.  As the seekbar moves, I can change the background color of the popup items.   I need to set the text color of all items black for light background colors and to white for all dark colors.

```
    if ( pos == object.COLOR_INDEX) {
             //change spinner Background and Text color
             spinner.setBackgroundColor(Colors.BACKGROUND[objectCurrent.getParams(pos)]);
             TextView v ; int ct ;
             for(int i=0; i<(ct=spinner.getChildCount()); ++i) {
                 v= (TextView)spinner.getChildAt(i);
                 v.setTextColor(Colors.FOREGROUND[objectCurrent.getParams(pos)]);
             }



             ColorDrawable drawable=(ColorDrawable) spinner.getBackground() ;
             spinner.setPopupBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
             spinner.setSelection(0); spinner.setSelection(pos);
    }
```

I have not found a way to do this.  Looping through spinner.getChildAt(i) affects only the currently displayed item and not those hidden on the popup.

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This apparently does the trick:

```
    Resources res=getResources();
    final List<String> spinnerItems=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.spin_settings)));

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerItems){
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,
                    parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Colors.FOREGROUND[obj.getParams(param.COLOR_INDEX)]);
            ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Colors.BACKGROUND[obj.getParams(param.COLOR_INDEX)]);


            return v;
        }

    };

     aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);



    spinnerLeft.setAdapter(aa);
    spinnerRight.setAdapter(aa);
```

The getDropDownView event seems to get raised for every item on the drop down list.

Comment: Why are you passing `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` to the constructor, and then setting dropdown resource of `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`?